# 'OcrEngineMode' does not contain a definition for 'TesseractCubeCombined'

Tags: c#, emgucv, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I'm trying to just simply run the code from [this example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/License_Plate_Recognition_in_CSharp), but I get loads of errors including

> 'OcrEngineMode' does not contain a definition for 'TesseractCubeCombined'

What is going on here? Am I using the wrong version of `emgu` and if so, could anyone help me figure out which version I need?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you told us *which* version of EmguCV you are using. There is a working License Plate Detection example in EmguCV 3.4.1. Check it out.

Doug

Comment: I downloaded and tried to run that sample but I just get errors like `DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` and `TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.` And when I try adding `cvextern` as a reference I get `A reference to cvextern.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assemly or COM component`